# ffmpeg unable to find a suitable output format for '\'

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying following command to concatenate my 4 MP4 video files using FFmpeg with concat filter, but it gives the error:

> Unable to find a suitable output format for '\'

Command:

```
F:\Partition C Backup\Downloads\Compressed\ffmpeg-20170817-92da230-win64-shared\
ffmpeg-20170817-92da230-win64-shared\bin>ffmpeg -i "long name with spaces 1.mp4"
-i "long name with spaces 2.mp4" -i "long name with spaces 3.mp4"
-i "long name with spaces 4.mp4" \ -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0]
[2:v:0] [2:a:0] [3:v:0] [3:a:0] concat=n=4:v= 1:a=1 [v] [a]"
\ -map "[v]" -map "[a]" E:\FFmpeg.mp4
```

Please help me to find what is wrong syntax in this command.

Comment: Remove the `\\`. You probably copied these from a command formatted a bash-like shell.

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks it worked. But I like to know why I am getting "Network is too busy..." error in WMP after concatenating with above command? I even have KLCP Mega installed.

Comment: That's an entirely different question. Voting to close this as a typo.